# how to pass commas when entering in textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

We are developing a Worklight Hybrid mobile application using Jquery mobile.

I want to pass commas when entering digits in a number text field. Text field maxlength 9.

I want the control to show values like this **5,652,895**.

Please can anyone tell me where I am missing the logic?

[image]

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.value', function() {
    if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
      return value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
      ;
    });
});
```

```html
<input onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==9 && event.keyCode != 8)return false;"  id="txtVehicleValue" placeholder="Vehicle Value"  name="vehicleValue" class="value">
```

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/1kfsx6rp/15/

Comment: thanks Poria, but i want to dynamically pass the commas.

Comment: If you are using html5 control like type="number" then use pattern otherwise use jquery/javascript format onmouseout event.

Comment: try maskMoney:  http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Currency-Input-Filed-Mask-Plugin-maskmoney/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution for this Question**

```js
$(document).on('keyup', '.number', function() {
    if(event.which >= 37 && event.which <= 40) return;
    $(this).val(function(index, value) {
      return value
      .replace(/\D/g, "")
      .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
      ;
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="qic-form-group showError">
 <input onKeyDown="if(this.value.length==9 && event.keyCode != 8)return false;" class="clearTxtFld number" placeholder="Vehicle Value"  name="vehicleValue">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input class="number" onkeyup="addComma(this);">
```

Jquery:

```
function addComma(obj) {
      $(obj).val(function(index, value) {
        return value
        .replace(/\D/g, "")
        .replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
      });
}
```

Comment: thanks Jayesh.it's working in js fiddile but it's not working in mobile application

Comment: hmm yes.After .keyup function i write alert but it's not comming

Comment: updated code with function..try that..i hope it will work

Comment: Yes i try, when i entering fourth digit  it's automatically araising

Comment: jayesh,$(document).on('keyup', '.number', function()  i wrote this code after this line i am getting alert. and i am entering the number when i entering fourth digit  it's automatically araising. keyup it's working but commas not comming

Comment: Thanks so much for the helping Jayesh, i removed type="number"  in input tag  it's working.

Comment: jayesh, after entering total value i need to add dynamically decimal like 5,652,895.000